# Запуск функции в MainActivity из кастомного адаптера ListView

Tags: java, android

В адаптере обрабатываю нажатие кнопки:

```
final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.BtnDeleteNotes);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });
```

Как вызвать функцию в MainActivity, к примеру, `Delete();`?